# Which C# XML documentation comment tag is used for 'true', 'false' and 'null'?

Tags: c#, styles, literals, xml-documentation

Which C# XML documentation comment tag is used for the literals `true`, `false` and `null`?

In Microsoft's own documentation, these literals appear in **bold text**. For example, the documentation for the property [ArrayList.IsFixedSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.isfixedsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) appears as:

> **true** if the [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.ArrayList%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a fixed size; otherwise, **false**. The default is **false**.

None of [Microsoft's Recommended Tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx) seem to apply to this situation. The best fit appears to be [<c>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te6h7cxs%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), however `<c>true</c>` appears as `true` when the documentation is rendered by [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

However, using `<b>true</b>` with Doxygen yielded bold text as I surmised that it might. But that leaves me wondering about **the portability of using standard HTML tags** with other documentation generation tools such as [Sandcastle](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) and [GhostDoc](http://www.roland-weigelt.de/ghostdoc/).

Comment: I am using the <c> for all the boolean and its what is the standard that we follow to represent the bool values in the comments.

Comment: You can also use e.g. `<see langword="true">`. But it's not in bold text for me (I use Sandcastle), the font is in blue instead.

Comment: @fedab you forgot `/`:
`<see langword="true"/>`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You should use the `<see langword="true"/>` entry so that it works right for whatever language is being used.

Comment: In Microsoft's updated documentation on the page **Recommended XML tags for C# documentation comments**, see the topic [Generate links and references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#generate-links-and-references) which states for **see**: `langword="keyword"`: A language keyword, such as `true` or one of the other valid [keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/).

Answer (score 19):

Per GhostDoc's behavior, `<c>true</c>` is the correct answer. I've voted up saravanan's comment now that I've been able to confirm it.